# How do I write a function to work with a generic map and its entry type?

Tags: dictionary, generics, rust

I need function that protects my `HashMap` from overwriting already existing values, so I've written a simple function like this:

```
fn insert_or_panic<K, V>(m: &mut HashMap<K, V>, k: K, v: V)
where
    K: Hash + Eq,
{
    use std::collections::hash_map::Entry;
    match m.entry(k) {
        Entry::Vacant(o) => o.insert(v),
        Entry::Occupied(_) => panic!("attempt to overwrite entry in dictionary"),
    };
}
```

Now I want to generalize it to work with any kind of map:

```
fn generic_insert_or_panic<M, K, V>(m: &mut M, k: K, v: V)
where
    K: Hash + Eq,
    M: Map<K, V>,
{
    use std::collections::hash_map::Entry;
    match m.entry(k) {
        Entry::Vacant(o) => o.insert(v),
        Entry::Occupied(_) => panic!("attempt to overwrite entry in dictionary"),
    };
}
```

All methods of `HashMap` that I'm interested in are in its `impl` block not associated with any trait, so it looks like I have to implement a new trait:

```
trait Map<K: Hash + Eq, V> {
    fn entry(&mut self, key: K) -> Entry<K, V>;
}
```

Every map has it's own `Entry` type: `std::collections::hash_map::Entry` or `std::collections::btree_map::Entry` and I don't see a fitting trait to replace `Entry`. Is it time for another trait?

I feel that I'm going wrong direction. How to solve this problem?

---

I just started to learn Rust and some of my problems may look unrealistic and far-fetched, but I'm looking for ways to solve problems, not to work around them, or at least to know the limits of the language.

---

FAQ [explains](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/faq.html#what-are-higher-kinded-types) that higher-kinded types can solve this problem, but it is a big feature, so rust want to approach it carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it time for another trait?

Yes. No one has needed to have this particular generic expression, so you get to abstract across them yourself.

```
trait InsertOrPanic<K, V> {
    fn generic_insert_or_panic(&mut self, k: K, v: V);
}

use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::Hash;

impl<K, V> InsertOrPanic<K, V> for HashMap<K, V>
where
    K: Eq + Hash,
{
    fn generic_insert_or_panic(&mut self, k: K, v: V) {
        use std::collections::hash_map::Entry;

        match self.entry(k) {
            Entry::Vacant(o) => o.insert(v),
            Entry::Occupied(_) => panic!("attempt to overwrite entry in dictionary"),
        };
    }
}

use std::collections::BTreeMap;

impl<K, V> InsertOrPanic<K, V> for BTreeMap<K, V>
where
    K: Ord,
{
    fn generic_insert_or_panic(&mut self, k: K, v: V) {
        use std::collections::btree_map::Entry;

        match self.entry(k) {
            Entry::Vacant(o) => o.insert(v),
            Entry::Occupied(_) => panic!("attempt to overwrite entry in dictionary"),
        };
    }
}
```

Note that the bounds on the implementations of each is different (`Hash + Eq` vs. `Ord`), so they are pretty fundamentally different.

> I feel that I'm going wrong direction. How to solve this problem?
>
> I just started to learn Rust and some of my problems may look unrealistic and far-fetched, but I'm looking for ways to solve problems

You haven't provided enough information to justify your needs, so I'd challenge this statement. Generally you don't need to be generic over two types of maps because a problem domain naturally gravitates to one or the other.

Comment: `HashMap` and `BTreeMap` are quite different for the end user, but not for this generic code. Yes, they have different type requirements and operation complexity, but if I could say that K's type requirements are the same as for K in `M<K,V>` and complexity is the same as `M.entry()` it would be totally okay. Maybe I'm too exposed to C++ templates and I need to change the way I'm thinking about problems, but for now this seems to me as a limitation.

Answer (score 0):

You could create this trait

```
trait Map<K: Hash + Eq, V> {
    fn contains_key<Q>(&self, k: &Q) -> bool;
    where
        K: Borrow<Q>,
        Q: Hash + Eq + Ord + ?Sized,

    fn insert(&mut self, k: K, v: V) -> Option<V>;
}
```

and then just write your generic `insert_or_panic` to use `contains_key` and `insert` rather than the Entry API.

However, there are only two types of map, and their keys require different things, in particular the `BTreeMap` requires ordered keys. This sounds like a case where writing a generic function rather than two functions is overkill.

Comment: The entry API is more efficient. Having to first check if the key exists and then insert will have to lookup in the map twice.

Comment: Fine then because this is panicing on the value existing, just do the insert and panic if the return value is not `None`. You get better performance in the normal case, and you shouldn't care about the performance right before a panic anyway.